# Go loop through datastore cursor

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

Is there a way to loop through datastore results via a cursor, until there are no results?

I need to pull every single record and iterate through it. But it's like 4 million records. So I wanted to work in chunks of 1000 to start with.

I know the below won't work. But it's just to show the sort of logic I'm hoping for.

```
q := datastore.NewQuery("Foo").Limit(1000)
while t, err := models.Client.GetAll(models.Ctx, q, &results) {
  ...
  myCursor, err := t.Cursor()
  q.Start(cursor)
}
```

EDIT: Here is the only way I found how to do it. I'm sure there is a more elegant way.

```
limit := 1000
offset := 0
resultCount := 1
for resultCount > 0 {
    q := datastore.NewQuery("Foo").Limit(limit).Offset(offset)
    _, err := client.GetAll(ctx, q, &foo)
    checkErr(err)
    resultCount = len(foo)
    processPaths(foo)
    offset += resultCount

}
```

It doesn't actually use the cursor.

Comment: Is the example in the [cursor docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/query-cursors#query_cursor_example) insufficient?

Comment: Yes because it doesn't explain a few things. First, how to properly format cursorStr. Second, how to use it properly in a loop.

Comment: The cursor string is just an opaque Base64-encoded identifier provided by the datastore (via the `Cursor()` method).  You don't format it, you store it and use it for the next cursor iteration (if necessary.  If you're doing a pull-all-at-once, you don't even need to store it).  As for looping, the example shows you exactly how pull data using a cursor via a loop.

Comment: Funny, I saw both comments and I totally agreed with Chemdream, but then, I actually opened the link Kaedys posted and got surprised as it was actually a different cursor example that I just had read. :) And it's actually 100% complete.
[This is the cursor example that doesn't explain much.](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#cursors_limits_and_offsets)